# ICustomTypeDescriptor GetConverter implementation

Tags: c#, winforms, icustomtypedescriptor

I have a base class decorated with a `TypeDescriptionProviderAttribute` that points at a custom implementation of `ICustomTypeDescriptor`.

There is a derived class that is decorated with a `TypeConverterAttribute` to do custom type conversion.

`BaseClassTypeDescriptor` implements `ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter` by calling the static `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter` method.  That method takes two arguments: the type in question (which I have a reference to), and a flag that indicates whether or not to allow the custom behavior to be called.  This has to be set to `true` to prevent an infinite loop.

A stripped-down version of the code looks like this:

```
[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(BaseClassTypeDescriptionProvider))]
public class BaseClass
{
    public class BaseClassTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
    {
        public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType_, object instance_)
        {
            return new BaseClassTypeDescriptor(objectType_);
        }
    }

    public class BaseClassTypeDescriptor : ICustomTypeDescriptor 
    {
         private Type _type;

         public BaseClassTypeDescriptor(Type type_)
         {
             _type = type_;
         }

         TypeConverter ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()
         {
             return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(_type, true);
         }
    }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(MyTypeConverter))]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
}
```

The problem is that this flag seems to not only bypass `BaseClassTypeDescriptor`, but also seems to prevent .NET from recognizing the `TypeConverterAttribute` on the derived class.

I've worked around this by reimplementing the check for a `TypeConverterAttribute` inside my implementation of `MyCustomTypeConverter.GetConverter`, like so:

```
TypeConverter ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()
{
    object[] typeConverterAttributeArray = _type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TypeConverterAttribute), true);
    if (typeConverterAttributeArray.Length == 1)
    {
        TypeConverterAttribute a = (TypeConverterAttribute)typeConverterAttributeArray[0];
        Type converterType = MyTypeLoader.GetType(a.ConverterTypeName);
        return (TypeConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(converterType);
    }
    else
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(_type, true);
    }
}
```

This is far from an ideal solution.  Any suggestion as to how I can delegate that responsibility back where it belongs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the overload of `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(object component, bool noCustomTypeDesc)` seems to return the `TypeDescriptor` for the `Type` type, since it expects an instance.

I tried your example with

```
return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(Activator.CreateInstance(_type), true);
```

And got the infinite loop the `bool` value was supposed to prevent.

I don't know why this works this way, and whether this is documented somehow, but I bet they don't expect a `TypeDescriptionProvider` to call `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter()` at all.